# Works in Firefox but not IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I make use of the following to find a string in a particular element, if it exists, tick a checkbox. This works great on Firefox but not internet explorer (8). I am having trouble finding why.

```
$.fn.searchString = function(str) {
   return this.filter('*:contains("' + str + '")');
};

var myID = $('div').searchString(files_array[i].substr(-4));

alert(myID);//[object object]

alert(myID.children());//[object object]

myID.children().attr('checked', true);//does not tick checkbox

alert(myID.children().attr('checked'));//undefined
```

Does IE not like the children() function?

Thanks all for any help

Comment: Shot in the dark, but can you try `myID.children().attr('checked', 'checked');`?

Comment: "Works in Firefox but not IE"? Well that's a first!

Comment: Are you sure that the "substr(-4)" is doing what you think it's doing?

Comment: could you provide the related HTML snippet ?

Comment: could you attach some html & expand files_array please... or post the entire page thanks

Comment: Is the first child a checkbox? :) `.attr()` returns the attribute of the **first element in the set**...this may not be what you're after.

Comment: @Pointy - yes as it works in Firefox. @Pekka - I tried that and it didn't work. Do you know a way to get the ID of that JQuery object `myID`?

Comment: @Pekka "true" should work fine for "checked", assuming that the jQuery elements involved actually do refer to checkbox elements.

Comment: What does `searchString` do? I'm not seeing it in the jQuery API, but you're calling it on a jQuery object. Is it some kind of add-in?

Comment: If you walk through it with a debugger (there are two or three available for IE from Microsoft), where does it fail and how?

Comment: Also remember that a non-null jQuery object can be empty. Your alerts should not be just dumping that out - they should say `alert(myID.length)`

Comment: @Abs well "substr(-4)" always returns an empty string in IE!

Comment: @Pointy - that actually returns a 0 for me. So that must mean my search function isn't finding or is failing to find what I need.

Comment: @Abs see my answer - the call to substr(-4) is the problem.

Comment: @T.J. - its just a normal user function that should return the object that contains the string I am looking for, its not part of the JQuery core.

Comment: @Pointy - really! I just did a quick test and it just returned the whole string, I guess the sub string thing is the problem then since if that sub string doesn't happen it will never find the object!

Comment: Thanks Pointy! I used `substring(5,9)` instead. Do you want add an answer so I can select it as the correct one, I am sure someone will rip their hair out about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From MSDN, in reference to the "substr" function:

> Remarks
>
> If length is zero or negative, an empty string is returned. If not specified, the substring continues to the end of the string.

You're coming up with nothing from the original code that tries to set "myID".

Comment: Just to add, for me, the substr seems to return the whole string if I put in a negative number but Firefox seems to understand what I am trying to do and it returns the last set of characters.

Comment: I wish I found this: http://rapd.wordpress.com/2007/07/12/javascript-substr-vs-substring/ - If start is negative, Internet Explorer returns the whole string. That’s wrong! IE should use the last character in the string.

Comment: That's funny - much as I despise IE, the MSDN documentation is *usually* very accurate. Well in any case my IE spider sense started tingling as soon as I saw that "substr(-4)" call.

Answer (score 0):

See http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/167 for this bug and the resolution. I am just learning jQuery. The resolution in the page I am referring ask us to use  `$("#method-download").get(0).checked = true;` instead.

Comment: That is not necessary. Setting "checked" via "attr()" definitely works. I use it all over the place. You'll note that the bug you reference is 4 years old, and closed.

Comment: Not my downvote but I agree with it, you definitely need to check the status of any bug you find in google, it's status and date makes it completely irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks all. I am still learning. Actually I took interest in jQuery from a downvote only. Thanks to all.